# I'm having a problem with the DNS settings of my headless wordpress/reactjs based website

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, dns, devops, headless

I'm using a Wordpress headless cms solution as a backend and firebase as the frontend. 
Right now i have a domain name that has been bought from godaddy, i've pointed their nameservers to my hosting called hostinger.

So now if i got to the webpage https://www.isoftmix.be/wp-admin/ it correctly brings me to the wordpress CMS if i type https://www.isoftmix.be it brings to the frontend. The problem here is the URL changes to the temp URL firebase provides. I've tried a couple of things such as pointed the A records from goddady to firebase and having some kind of temp URL of the CMS backend but this just isn't good and feels really sloppy not to mention the URL just stopped working all together.

edit: https://isoftmix-8ad57.firebaseapp.com/ -> the link that should be changed to -> isoftmix.be

tl;dr : trying to have 1 domain name showing front & backend with 2 hostings.

Answer (score 0):

Serving both applications on the same dns zone might require a bit of trickery. To do something like that you would want the www dns zone to point to a load balancer. Then configure the load balancer to always default to the firebase app, except in the case you are trying to access wp-admin where it would load the traffic from wordpress.

Another option if your webhost won't allow you to have a load balancer you could use different dns zones within the same domain. For the www record there is documentation for pointing DNS at firebase: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

Then in your DNS create a new A record and point it to wordpress. The catch here is that it would need to be a different record than www, maybe admin.isoftmix.be as an example. This would require you to change the URL of your WordPress installation in your wp-config.php file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers guys. I had multiple attempts to set this up with Firebase & Hostinger. But right now i'm at a point where i need something working. So I've been thinking to start working with digital ocean's droplets and see if this will do the trick. I see there is more flexibility on my concept all together on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it could be a bit tricky but I think another type of solution could be to have firebase point to the main domain and have the cms point to a subdomain such as admin.isoftmix.be. Then you configure the front end and back end to communicate with each other. This avoids your DNS nightmare of having two applications point to the same DNS zone.